# Container View in Cocoa, Swap Contents at Runtime and Preserve Size

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

My view controller has an NSView that I am using as a container view.
I dragged the "Container View" from the library, deleted the segue and embedded view controller, added constraints to the superview (view controller's main view) and set up an outlet to the container view in the view controller's code.

So far so good.

I wish to swap the contents of the container view with the main view of several different view controllers, determined at runtime. I have succeeded in doing that, with code like this:

```
func swapContainerViewContents(with viewController: NSViewController) {
    self.containerView.subviews.foreach({ subview in 
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    })

    containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
}
```

This works, but as soon as I resize the window, the child view obviously stays at its original size (I haven't set up any constraints).

If instead, I add the necessary constraints:

```
let newView = viewController.view

containerView.addSubview(newView)

newView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
newView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

...now, the window can not be resized! (it is stuck at the subview's initial size).

**What is the way to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out all I needed to do is add this line before setting up my constraints:

```
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

It isn't clear to me why I should need this, given that the child view I want to add belongs to a view controller created from a **storyboard** (and those are supposed to already **not** translate autoresizing mask into constraints...?); this code should only be needed for views created programmatically...